Virtual threads in a Spring Boot applcation
This is the version of Spring Boot that I am using.
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

I have enabled virtual threads.
application.properties
spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true

I noticed that when I make a request to my RestController, the tomcat-handler-xx in the logs does not get reset. Is this a normal behavior? Will I run out of virtual threads?


Tomcat’s Virtual Thread implementation does not use Thread-Pool. Per the documentation, the virtual thread implementation use new virtual thread to execute each task. Requires Java 21+.
